# How many times a specific day has passed between two dates?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

What I am trying to do is get the amount of times a specific day of each month has passed between two dates.

For example:
I want how many times the 16th of each month has passed between 11-21-2011 to 5-15-2013. 
In this case it would be 17.

I've been having the hardest time figuring this out. The only way I know how to go about this is to write a bunch of if statements checking for how many years have passed, then how many months have passed, etc. Is there any faster way, like with NSDate or something?

Comment: No, I think you'd have to iterate from the start date to the end date, incrementing months/years via an `NSDateComponents` object, which will be used to create the comparison `NSDate` (Jan 16th 2011, Feb 16th 2011 ... Jan 16th 2012, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/trojanfoe/8454685) of a working example.  The guts of the code is:

```
const NSCalendarUnit units = NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSCalendarCalendarUnit|NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:units
                                      fromDate:startDate];
if ([comps day] > wantDay)
    nextMonth(comps);       // Missed the first month
[comps setDay:wantDay];

NSInteger count = 0;
while (YES) {
    NSDate *compareDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
    if (!compareDate) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create compare date");
        return 5;
    }
    NSLog(@"Comparing %@", [formatter stringFromDate:compareDate]);
    if ([compareDate compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
        break;
    count++;
    nextMonth(comps);
}
```

Where `nextMonth()` is:

```
static void nextMonth(NSDateComponents *comps) {
    NSInteger month = [comps month];
    if (month == 12) {
        [comps setYear:[comps year] + 1];
        [comps setMonth:1];
    } else {
        [comps setMonth:month + 1];
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
$ ./dateiter 19990112 19990212 12
2014-01-16 13:06:53.189 dateiter[16740:707] start-date=1999-01-12 00:00:00 +0000, end-date=1999-02-12 00:00:00 +0000, want-day=12
2014-01-16 13:06:53.189 dateiter[16740:707] Comparing 19990112
2014-01-16 13:06:53.190 dateiter[16740:707] Comparing 19990212
2014-01-16 13:06:53.190 dateiter[16740:707] Comparing 19990312
2014-01-16 13:06:53.190 dateiter[16740:707] 2 months

$ ./dateiter 20111121 20130515 16
2014-01-16 13:10:53.318 dateiter[16810:707] start-date=2011-11-21 00:00:00 +0000, end-date=2013-05-15 00:00:00 +0000, want-day=16
2014-01-16 13:10:53.319 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20111216
2014-01-16 13:10:53.319 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20120116
2014-01-16 13:10:53.319 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20120216
2014-01-16 13:10:53.319 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20120316
2014-01-16 13:10:53.320 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20120416
2014-01-16 13:10:53.320 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20120516
2014-01-16 13:10:53.320 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20120616
2014-01-16 13:10:53.320 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20120716
2014-01-16 13:10:53.321 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20120816
2014-01-16 13:10:53.321 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20120916
2014-01-16 13:10:53.321 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20121016
2014-01-16 13:10:53.322 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20121116
2014-01-16 13:10:53.322 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20121216
2014-01-16 13:10:53.322 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20130116
2014-01-16 13:10:53.322 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20130216
2014-01-16 13:10:53.323 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20130316
2014-01-16 13:10:53.323 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20130416
2014-01-16 13:10:53.323 dateiter[16810:707] Comparing 20130516
2014-01-16 13:10:53.323 dateiter[16810:707] 17 months
```

Comment: This looks great! Haven't really dug into the abilities of NSDateComponents yet, so this will be a great learning experience. I will definitely give it a try this weekend when I get the chance. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
//your dates
//NSDate *fromDateTime = dateFromString:@"11-21-2011";
//NSDate *toDateTime = dateFromString:@" 5-15-2013";

NSDate *fromDate;
NSDate *toDate;

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&fromDate
             interval:NULL forDate:fromDateTime];
[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&toDate
             interval:NULL forDate:toDateTime];

NSDateComponents *difference = [calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                                           fromDate:fromDate toDate:toDate options:0];

NSInteger occurance = [difference month];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:fromDate];
NSInteger fromDay = [components day];

if (fromDay < 16) {
    occurance = occurance + 1;
}

components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:toDate];
NSInteger toDay = [components day];
if (toDay > 16) {
    occurance = occurance + 1;
}

//now occurance will be number of times the 16th of each month has passed between fromDate and toDate
```